# Development SQL next to a live production server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I currently have a setup of

- Compute Engine. Shows a website and handles a lot of data incoming through feeds
- Cloud SQL server. Holds all the data

Now my website is getting very busy and the data handling is getting too much for one server.

I would like to run the website seperately from the data handling so my visitors don't experience lagspikes when large files are loaded. I can easily do that for the Compute Engines, but I would like to have one dedicated Cloud SQL server for the website too which is just mirrored every hour or something.

Is it possible to have a mirrored production SQL server, and how?

Comment: You may want to check CloudSQL replication options here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/. If your website only reads the db, you may be interested in Read replica.

Comment: Hey there Lundin! I am going to check it out. It's gonna be read only indeed!